# python - pandas: function to replicate the creation of a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, python-itertools

I am trying to replicate the variable `aux_35`, because I have some missing values in my database. Here is a little sample of the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import dateutil.relativedelta as rd
import math
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import repeat
from operator import itemgetter

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pdt_050':[[0.683522, 0.26141],
[0.683522, 0.26141],
[0.683522, 0.26141],
[0.726501, 0.373269, 0.159278],
[0.726501, 0.373269, 0.159278],
[0.596246, 0.288327, 0.120612],
[0.353175, 0.314364, 0.159139],
[0.595886, 0.25835],
[0.582035],
[0.726501, 0.373269, 0.159278],
[0.583463, 0.366378, 0.262419, 0.19254, 0.1288, 0.064597],
[0.751279, 0.436349, 0.248187, 0.110235]
],
'aux_35': [0.683522, 0.683522,0.683522, 0.726501, 0.726501, 0.596246, 0.159139,0.25835,0.582035, 0.373269, 0.583463,
0.436349
],
'tob': [1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1
]
})
```

[image]

Basically `aux_35` take data from `pdt_050` and assign the value based on the variable `tob`. For example: when the number of tob is equal to 1 or 0, aux_35 should be the first element of the array pdt_050 and when tob is a number that is higher than the length of elements on pdt_050, aux_35 should be equal to the last element in pdt_050; as you can see on the row number six.

I was making the function to replicate that process:

```
def mmonths(df):
    pdo = []
    pdoriginal = df['pdt_050']
    tob_y = df['aux_35'].astype(int)
    for i in range(len(tob_y)):
        tob = tob_y[i]
        try:
            pdo.append(pdoriginal[i][(tob)])
        except:
            pdo.append(pdoriginal[i][0])
            
    return pdo

df['replica']  = mmonths(df)
```

But, as you can see in the following pic, it is not good. Can you help me please?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets apply a custom indexer function along column axis

```
def indexer(a, i):
    return a[max(1, min(int(i), len(a))) - 1]

df['aux_35'] = df.apply(lambda s: indexer(s['pdt_050'], s['tob']), axis=1)
```

Result

```
                                                      pdt_050  tob    aux_35
0                                         [0.683522, 0.26141]    1  0.683522
1                                         [0.683522, 0.26141]    1  0.683522
2                                         [0.683522, 0.26141]    1  0.683522
3                              [0.726501, 0.373269, 0.159278]    1  0.726501
4                              [0.726501, 0.373269, 0.159278]    1  0.726501
5                              [0.596246, 0.288327, 0.120612]    1  0.596246
6                              [0.353175, 0.314364, 0.159139]   14  0.159139
7                                         [0.595886, 0.25835]    2  0.258350
8                                                  [0.582035]    1  0.582035
9                              [0.726501, 0.373269, 0.159278]    1  0.726501
10  [0.583463, 0.366378, 0.262419, 0.19254, 0.1288, 0.064597]    0  0.583463
11                   [0.751279, 0.436349, 0.248187, 0.110235]    1  0.751279
```